# Is it possible to modify default statusline without resetting it to blank?

Tags: vimrc, statusline

Normally, if you add something like

```
set setting+=value
```

into your .vimrc, the value will be appended to the existing ones. For example:

```
set formatoptions+=j  " => tcqj
```

However, it seems it doesn't work the same for status line.

```
set statusline=2
set statusline+=\ %{&filetype}

for the javascript file, expected status line:
[No Name]           0,0-1            All javascript

for the javascript file, actual status line:
javascript (and nothing more)
```

So, why using something like

```
set statusline=2
set statusline+=\ %{&filetype}
```

works the same as if we would use

```
set statusline=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=\ %{&filetype}
```

?

And how to workaround this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `:help 'statusline'` is empty and Vim uses a hardcoded routine to fill the status line. When it is non-empty, the hardcoded value is ignored, leaving you with a blank slate.

When you do any of the following, you effectively set `statusline` to a non-empty value which makes the hardcoded one disappear:

```
set statusline=foo
set statusline+=bar
set statusline^=baz
```

That is how `statusline` has been working for decades and there is no option, command-line flag, or even compile flag to change that.

The only way to augment the default status line with *arbitrary information* is to replicate the default status line as indicated in the relevant documentation:

```
Emulate standard status line with 'ruler' set  
  :set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

In your case:

```
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
set statusline+=\ %{&filetype}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `set +=` doesn’t work to append to the default status line format is that the default for the `'statusline'` option is actually an empty string, and Vim renders a default status line whenever that option is empty.

Since the default is empty, `set status line+=anything` will modify it to be non-empty and then the default behavior will no longer trigger, so in effect you’ll get *only* the part that you added and not the default fields.

What complicates matters a little bit is that the code that implements the default format is actually hardcoded into the Vim binary, which is code written in C. In other words, Vim doesn’t use a default format string for the default case. The default behavior also depends on features compiled into Vim, also on the state of other options (such as `ser ruler`) and some of the spacing of the line numbers is hard or impossible to reproduce exactly with the format primitives available for the `'statusline'` value.

Having said that, you can get a good approximation of the default, with the `'ruler'` option enabled, with:

```
set statusline=%f\ %h%w%m%r\ %=%(%l,%c%V\ %=\ %P%)
```

So you can start with that setting in your vimrc and then use `set +=` to append to it, accomplishing roughly the same effect you initially intended.